# Validating Default value

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am trying to validate null or empty values for the variables `$var1` and `$var2`. Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

`testing.ps1`:

```
Param (
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][String]$var1 = $defaultvar1,
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][String]$var2 = $defaultvar2
)
Write-Host "Value of Variable 1 : $var1 "
Write-Host "Value of Variable 2 : $var2 "
```

Output:

```
PS> .\testing.ps1
Value of Variable 1 :
Value of Variable 2 :
PS> $defaultvar1=123
PS> $defaultvar2=678
PS> .\testing.ps1
Value of Variable 1 : 123
Value of Variable 2 : 678
PS> $defaultvar2=""
PS> .\testing.ps1
Value of Variable 1 : 123
Value of Variable 2 :
```

Comment: the validate stuff only applies to _inbound_ parameter values. your assignment of external $Vars as the default value is not only quite unusual, it means those values will NOT be validated. [*grin*]

Comment: I could see using a variable if the function and the variable were defined in a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) points out:

**Parameter *default values* are *not* validated** - the assumption is that you, as the function author, will ensure that the values are valid.

A simpler example:

```
PS> & { param([ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $foo = '') "foo: [$foo]" }
foo: []
```

That is, `''` was happily accepted as the default value, even though it contradicts `[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]`.

Additionally, **you generally shouldn't use *function-external variable values* as parameter default values**, because it'll make the function's behavior hard to predict.

Instead, use:

- literals (e.g., `$foo = 'bar'`)

or

- expressions (e.g., `$foo = (Get-Date)`)

That said, as [Mike Shepard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36429/mike-shepard) points out, **referencing variables *is* an option, *if***:

- your function is defined *inside a module*,
- and the variables being referenced are *defined in that same module*.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. My solution was to validate twice:

```
Param (
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][String]$var1 = $script:defaultVar1,
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][String]$var2 = $script:defaultVar2
)
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($var1)){ throw "var1 was not provided and defaultVar1 is null or empty" }
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($var2)){ throw "var2 was not provided and defaultVar2 is null or empty" }

Write-Host "Value of Variable 1 : $var1 "
Write-Host "Value of Variable 2 : $var2 "
```

The `ValidateNotNullOrEmpty` attribute takes care of validating inbound parameters, while `IsNullOrEmpty` handles the edge case where `defaultVar1` or `defaultVar2` are empty

I find this pattern useful when writing a module where the user can configure default values for commonly used options.